# mvc 4 - UserProfile with ID long

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement a project with MVC 4 and I'm facing the following problem. It's simple, but I couldnt find the solution.

I need the table userProfille with the ID typed with long, but this is not possible because in the Filter the method:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Context", "Users", "ID", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);
```

, must have an ID field typed as INT ( the method description says `"userIdColumn: the name of the database column that contains user IDs. This column must be typed as an integer-int"`).

So, any simple suggestion?

Comment: Why does it need to be long -- going to somehow exhaust all the possible integers? I haven't found a better solution yet, but it is worth noting that MVC 5 uses GUID strings instead of integers for user IDs.

Comment: The code will be used in a Audit Framework so there will be a lot of numbers for the ID field. We have already solved this. We changed our abstract Model of the Audit Framework to choose the type of the ID field. That solves! But I want to know if this question has a solution without changing the Audit...